# Different result for the same mathematical operation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Python3 and numpy and I'm doing the following:

```
diff1 = np.abs(self.trainX - sample_repeated)
diff2 = np.abs(sample_repeated - self.trainX)
print("diff1 equals diff2?")
if(np.array_equal(diff1,diff2)): 
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

I expected diff1 to be equal to diff2. Any idea why the code always prints "No"? All the arrays have the same same (self.trainX, sample_repeated, diff1 and diff2).

NB: numpy docs report that array_equal is *"True if two arrays have the same shape and elements, False otherwise."*

Solved: you arrays was uint8 and that leads to overflow. You must cast them to int before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Floating points always have inaccuracies, so it is never advisable to compare with == or similar.

Comment: That duplicate-link is not answering this imho.

Comment: I have checked and all the arrays written in the code are uint8. What if it tries to do the sum 255 + 255? Overflow?

Comment: Everybody take notice: this question is about **uint8**, not float!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: you arrays was uint8 and that leads to overflow. You must cast them to int before